# Is there a way to have a static readonly field in an abstract class to be instantiated in derived classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, abstract-class, readonly

Is there a way to have a static readonly field in an abstract class to be instantiated in derived classes?

Instead of having a `static readonly` field in each derived class, I'd prefer if it were in their base class and each derived will instantiate its own unique field (the field will have different values in each derived class).

For example something like this: (but it doesn't work)

```
public static void Main()
{
    B b = new B(); //TypeInitializationException
    var q = b.X;
}

public abstract class A
{
    protected static readonly List<string> x;
}

public class B : A
{
    public List<string> X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }
    static B()
    {
        x.Add("asdf");
        x.Add("qwer");
        //or do this instead but it gives an error
        //x = new List<string>() { "qwer", "asdf" }; 
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    public List<string> X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }
    static C()
    {
        x.Add("rrrr");
        x.Add("tttt");
    }
}
```

Comment: The words `static` and `instance` are inherently opposed...

Comment: Do you want B and C to share a list, and both add items to it in their static ctors? Or do you want B and C to have *separate* static lists?

Comment: I want `B` and `C` to have different static lists,  I don't care about `A`. @Blorgbeard

Comment: You know your code only fails because `x` is not initialized? Do this: `protected static readonly List<string> x = new List<string>();`

Comment: You can create a read only property.

Comment: Well, your code defines only one list, `x`. So they are currently sharing a list. Inheritance doesn't work with `static`, so you cannot specify static fields/properties that way. You will have to give each class their own static field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "instantiate" a `static` field. There's no way for `A` to specify that all derived classes will have a particular `static` field or property.

Even if you fix your TypeLoadException by initializing `A.x`:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected static readonly List<string> x = new List<string>();
}
```

You can see that `B` and `C` are both using the same underlying list:

```
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
c.X.Dump();     // "asdf, qwer, rrrr, tttt"
```

If you want a class to have a static property, you have to give it a static property. It cannot inherit it from a base class.

Answer (score 1):

If you catch the exception, there is an inner exception of NullReferenceException. Try initialising the member `x`:

```
protected static readonly List<string> x = new List<string>();
```